# How to solve HouseRobber Leet Code in Python Stuck?

Tags: python

You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have security systems connected and it will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.

Given an integer array nums representing the amount of money of each house, return the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police.

```
class Solution(object):
    def rob(self, nums):
        if len(nums) <= 2:
            return max(nums)
        
        temp = 0
        for i in range(2, len(nums)):
            if i == len(nums):
                sum = nums[i] + nums[0]
                for j in range(0, len(nums)-3):
                    first = nums[i] + nums[j]
                    if first > sum:
                        sum = first
            else:
                sum = max(nums[i-2] + nums[i], nums[i], nums[i] + nums[0])
            nums[i] = sum
        return max(nums)
```

Passes almost all test cases but fails when input array is something like [1,3,1,3,100] when output should be 103, but gives 102 instead .

Comment: `i == len(nums)` will never be true inside the loop, since the upper bound of `range` is exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        length = len(nums)
        if length <= 2:
            return max(nums)
        
        nums[2] = nums[0] + nums[2]
        for i in range(3, length):
            nums[i] += max(nums[i-2], nums[i-3])
            
        return max(nums[-1], nums[-2])
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I figured it out by using a temp variable. Using Rob1 and Rob2 to track the maximum $ of robbing every other house.